# Using openssl command in a RPM spec file

Tags: openssl, rpm

I'm a beginner using rpm spec file.

I am trying to use the open ssl command to generate a certificate in my rpm spec file but it seems the command is unknown :
openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -passin pass:xxxx -in certificate.p12 -out outCertificate.crt
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.MRtWoV: line 43: openssl: command not found

I have well add openssl in the "Requires" field like below :

```
Requires(pre): openssl
Provides: xxxxx
```

and in the install part I did:

```
%install
 openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -passin pass:xxxx -in certificate.p12 -out outCertificate.crt
```

Am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The sections `%prep`, `%build`, and `%install` are executed on the builder. During the execution of the `rpmbuild`. If you want to execute the command on the client machine during installation of rpm you have to use `%pre` or `%post`.